# displaying specific text on tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm editing a tumblr theme, and I have some issues with displaying some text attached to the post.

So, every post (which is a image) has his own info, inserted as html in comments:

```
<div class="project_type">Book</div>
<div class="project_name">Bobby Smith</div>
```

The divs are hidden, and they are only displayed on mouse over, but the js code that I wrote is showing the divs of every post, overlayed. Here is the js:

```
$('.post_relative').hover(function() {
  $(".project_type, .project_name").show()
  },
  function(){
    $(".project_type, .project_name").hide()
  }
)
```

How can I show only the info of the hovering image?

here is the link to the page as well [7287.tumblr.com](http://7287.tumblr.com)

Thanks

Comment: Scope your selectors: `$(".project_type, .project_name", this).show()` or `$(this).find(".project_type, .project_name").show()`

Comment: thanks. it was so simple...